# Restored phone without backing up first

Tags: backup, restore

I have never backed up my phone (stupid, I know) and just upgraded to iOS 7. Unfortunately something went wrong and it reset everything. It gave me options to set up as new phone or a previous back up. The last back up I did was from my old phone 2 years ago! Is there a program out there that can help restore my old photos/info?

Answer (score 1):

No. If your iPhone have been wiped all data is lost. 
I just wondered why the last backup is 2 years old because before the iOS upgrade a backup should have been made.

You should consider using iCloud so regular backups of some data (contacts, calendar, notes, photos, App data) will be made without your interaction.